# Using CSS to remove the second occurrence of a select result

Tags: html, css

I am using an HTML template that has 3 blocks in the footer that are divs with classes: `col-md-6 col-lg-4`. Using CSS I would like to remove the second one that is selected from the class filter since the template plugin does not allow me to add JavaScript.
Please see HTML below.

```
<div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="iq-fancy-box-04">
                <div class="iq-icon">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="ion-ios-location-outline"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fancy-content">
                    <h5>Address</h5>
                    <span>#################</span>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="iq-fancy-box-04">
                <div class="iq-icon">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fancy-content">
                    <h5>Phone</h5>
                    <span class="lead"><a href="tel:"></a></span>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="iq-fancy-box-04">
                <div class="iq-icon">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="ion-ios-email-outline"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="fancy-content">
                    <h5>Email</h5>
                    <span><a href="mailto:#########">########</a></span>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `const removeNth = function(el, n){el.removeChild(el.querySelectorAll('*')[n])}`

Comment: this is javascript. i cannot run JS on this page because it's a CMS that only allow css changes.

Comment: .col-md-6.col-lg-4:nth-child(2){
  display: none;
}   , we cann't remove elements from css but we can hide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `.col-md-6.col-lg-4:nth-child(2) { display: none; }` to your CSS and you`re fine:

```css
.col-md-6.col-lg-4:nth-child(2) { 
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="iq-fancy-box-04">
                <div class="iq-icon">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="ion-ios-location-outline"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fancy-content">
                    <h5>Address</h5>
                    <span>#################</span>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="iq-fancy-box-04">
                <div class="iq-icon">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fancy-content">
                    <h5>Phone</h5>
                    <span class="lead"><a href="tel:"></a></span>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="iq-fancy-box-04">
                <div class="iq-icon">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="ion-ios-email-outline"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="fancy-content">
                    <h5>Email</h5>
                    <span><a href="mailto:#########">########</a></span>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
```

`:nth-child(n)` can be used to select the nth element of a specific class or tag. n declares the order of the element. So `.someClass:nth-child(5)` means that you apply a rule for the 5th element of class `someClass`.

Answer (score 0):

use CSS:

```
 :nth-child(2) { 
      display:none;
    }
```